# Box has 10 balls, 6 black, 4 white. Three drawn, color not recorded. What is the probability the fourth ball is white?

Tags: probability-theory

In this question we assume the $10$ balls are equally likely to be drawn from the box.

What I did was to partition this and say:
$P(\text{Fourth Ball is white}) = P(4^{th} \text{ is } W|3 \text{ are } W) + P(4^{th} \text{ is } W|2 \text{ are } W, 1 B) + P(4^{th} \text{ is } W|1 \text{ is } W , 2 B) + P(4^{th} \text{ is } W|0 \text{ are } W, 3 \text{ are } B)$.

Doing this gave me a number greater than 1. Not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: The answer is (I think clearly) $4/10$. If you *really* want to do it the hard way, multiply the probability the $4$-th is white given the first $3$ are by the probability the first $3$ are, same with the others, and add up.

Comment: 4/10 is the correct answer. I was confused because if we draw 3 balls and then don't put them back in, then how can we still be choosing from 10 balls? Or if it doesn't specify that the balls were put back in or not, then we assume they are put back in?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether they were put back in or not. I think it is intended they are NOT put back in (that makes things somewhat less obvious). Any sequence of $4$ balls is just as likely as any other sequence. If $10$ people are put in line at random, the probability Charlie is $4$-th is $1/10$. The probability the $4$-th is white is the same as the probability the $10$-th is, or the first.

Answer (score 1):

We described the easy way in the comments. So let's do it the hard way. Let $B_0$ be the event there are $0$ black in the first $3$, $B_1$ be the event there is $1$ black in the first $3$. Define $B_2$ and $B_3$ analogously. Let $W$ be the event the $4$-th is white. Then
$$\Pr(W)=\Pr(B_0\cap W)+\Pr(B_1\cap W)+\Pr(B_2\cap W)+\Pr(B_3\cap W).$$
Now let us calculate the various probabilities.

For example, $\Pr(B_0\cap W)=\Pr(W|B_0)\Pr(B_0)$. We have $\Pr(W|B_0)=\frac{1}{7}$ and $\Pr(B_0)=\frac{4}{10}\cdot\frac{3}{9}\cdot \frac{2}{7}$. Another expression for $\Pr(A_0)$ is $\frac{\binom{6}{0}\binom{4}{3}}{\binom{8}{3}}$.

Let's do another one. We have $\Pr(B_1\cap W)=\Pr(W|B_1)\Pr(B_1)$. We have $\Pr(W|B_1)=\frac{2}{7}$. And $\Pr(B_1)$ can be done in various ways. For instance it is $\frac{\binom{6}{1}\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{10}{3}}$.

Now you can do the remaining two calculations, for $B_2$ and $B_3$, add up, and simplify. After a while you should get $4/10$. And the unpleasantness of the work will show how useful the other viewpoint is.